# asp.net mvc - one door filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, filter, get

I need fire a filter method with all string in GET or POST value from http request before it was bind into controller action

Can i do it in Global.asax.cs? and if yes, can u give me more details or example (great) about this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in Global.asax.cs for *all* requests by

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   //Look at HttpContext.Current.Request to grab request values 
}
```

Model binding occurs before action filters run. If you want to write a filter that runs before model binding, you could write an IAuthorizationFilter which runs before model binders.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can with an action filter.

Try this [article](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Logging_with_ASPNET_MVC_Action_Filters.aspx).

Comment: with this how i can get, set value will bind into action parameter